# mediabutton won't control animateinline

Tags: animate, media9, javascript

I am displaying an `animateinline` animation which loops through some frames. I now would like to have a "continue"-button to jump the animation to the next cycle of frames.

If I understand the `animate` documentation (page 14) correctly the following should do the trick.

But it doesn't. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{animate}

% mytimeline.txt
\begin{filecontents*}{mytimeline.txt}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------  
%[*]:[new frame rate]:[<list of transparencies>][:<JavaScript>]  
% `*' in the first column pauses animation
%-------------------------------------------------------------------  
::0
::1
::2
::3
::4 : anim.myAnim.frameNum=0;  % Loop the firstpart
::5 
::6 
::7 
::8 
::9
::9:  anim.myAnim.frameNum=5; % Loop the second part
\end{filecontents*} 

\begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{animateinline}[ 
  label=myAnim, 
  autoplay, loop,  
  width=\linewidth, 
  begin={\begin{minipage}[c][5cm][c]{5cm}}, 
  end={\end{minipage}}, 
  timeline=mytimeline.txt
]{4}% 
%create "transparencies", to be arranged according to timeline 
  \multiframe{10}{Number=0+1}{% 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[font=\Huge] at (0,0) {\Number};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  } 
\end{animateinline}% 
% put a "continue"-button to jump to frame 6 in the animation "myAnim"
\mediabutton[jsaction={anim['myAnim'].frameNum=7;}]{Continue}
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

I am using pdflatex and Adobe Reader DC.

**ADDITION**
While I'm playing with it. Even a `jsaction={app.alert('Hello World');}` does not do anything. Is JavaScript possibly blocked by the reader I'm using?

Comment: Ups. Seems to be a bug. `\mediabutton` is currently non-functional. Need to look into this. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: New version 0.83, 2017/07/27 of `media9` uploaded to CTAN. Should be available within next 48 hours.

Comment: For the impatient: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agrahn/media9/master/media9.sty

Comment: @AlexG Can you explain what happened? Did Adobe Reader change?

Comment: @Manuel There was an `l3kernel` update recently which changed the behaviour of `\bool_if:n(TF)` from lazy to thorough evaluation of boolean expressions. This made fixing several l3 based packages necessary. The first try in the case of `media9` (v. 0.81, 2017/07/24) failed, but 0.83 as of yesterday should be ok.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the issue it reports has been resolved in the meantime. A new  package version is available on CTAN and via the package managers of TeXLive and MiKTeX.